# jquery responsive Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu

i have create a Navigation  (my first bigger script - Im learning ). I have nothing found on google who helps me.

I would use on Desktop , and mobile devices.

On Desktop it works and if i resize the desktop width it change to the mobile version. If i show on a mobile device i have only the desktop version.

http://www.kcserver.info/testarea/video2brain/nav/kreativ-nav/nav.html

The Javascript

---

```
// Navigation Script

$(function () {

    // Reload the Script after Resize of the Window 
    $(window).bind('resize', function (e) {
        if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
        window.RT = setTimeout(function () {
            this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
        }, 200);

    });

    // end Reload of the script

    $(window).load(function () {
        // Cache the elements we'll need
        var menu = $('#nav-bar');
        var menuList = menu.find('ul:first');
        var listItems = menu.find('li').not('#responsive-menu');

        // Create responsive Menu Version 4Version 4
        menuList.prepend('<li id="responsive-menu"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>'); // here you can change the text of the repsonsive Menu

        // show the responsiv menu links
        menu.on('click', '#responsive-menu', function () {
            listItems.slideToggle();
            listItems.addClass('collapsed');
        });
    });
});


// Now the schript change  from Desktop to responsive by 681 px. You can change this value. Dont forget to change the mediaqueries in the nav.css File
$(function () {
    //
    if ($(window).width() > 681) {
        $("ul#menu li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").addClass("active");
        $("ul#menu li").hover(function () {

            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
            $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideDown(300); // speed of the slide

        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideUp(200); // speed of the slide
        });
    } else {
        $("ul#menu li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").addClass("subnav");
        var $mobil = $("ul#menu li ");
        $mobil.children("ul").css("display", "none");
        $mobil.filter(":has(ul)").children(":first-child").click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle(); // animation to sho teh menu
            //$(this).parent().siblings().children("ul:visible").slideUp();  // activate this if you will sho only 1 activ Menupoint
            $(this).parent().removeClass('closed');

        });
    }
});

//

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($('body').width() < 960) {
        console.log("Less than 960");

    } else {
        console.log("More than 960");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, your problem lies in your HTML-construct, not the JS-Script.

Did you add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your header?

Further Information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag